# How to draw on buffered image with java graphics?

Tags: java, file-io, github, bufferedimage, graphics2d

My issue: Every time I create graphics from a buffered image and then draw another buffered image to the graphics I get an image that is blank.

My code is as follows.

```
Graphics2D g2d = atlas.createGraphics();
// images[i] is a buffered image read the fileio
g2d.drawImage(images[i], null, x, y); // Image is not blank, been tested
g2d.dispose();
// then save image
```

Ironically after trying to create a self contained example which is as follows... it worked. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong in my code and I am wondering if it is because maybe an image is not static, **could an image or another variable not being static affect my drawing?**

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String FOLDER_LOCATION = "./Images/";

        BufferedImage atlas = new BufferedImage(2048, 2048, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage redSquare = readImage(FOLDER_LOCATION + "red.png");

        Graphics2D g2d = atlas.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(redSquare, null, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();

        writeImage(atlas, FOLDER_LOCATION + "atlas.png");
    }

    public static BufferedImage readImage(String location) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(location);
            img = ImageIO.read(is);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static void writeImage(BufferedImage bi, String location) {
        try {
            File file = new File(location);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

After I save the image I see just a blank 2048 by 2048 image. I printed the entire image out and I get (0, 0, 0), but if I print out any of the image I am drawing to the atlas I get something like (72, 32, 283).

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong, but my entire source code for this project is here: https://github.com/gemurdock/jTextureAtlas and the branch I am working on is here: https://github.com/gemurdock/jTextureAtlas/tree/alpha.

**You have to look at the alpha branch to see my code**

Comment: Rather than ask volunteers to muck through many classes and thousands of lines of code, most unrelated to the problem, perhaps you want to put in the effort to first try to isolate the problem, and then post a small compilable and runnable program here to this site that demonstrates the problem and that we can test and modify, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Doing this will increase your odds of getting a decent answer quickly.

Comment: actually not a big project, like 6 small classes... anyways I will try to isolate it for you

Comment: Great, then it shouldn't be difficult for you to create this small program. Again, please understand that we're all volunteers, and we greatly appreciate all efforts you can do to help make it easy to help you. Thus the onus of effort here should be on you. Please check out the [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) link, and please let me know if anything there confuses you. Then, again, if you want a quick decent solution, consider creating and posting here as an edit to your question, your SSCCE.

Comment: by try I mean will do as an edit above. i know this and even when I ask myself how I would want to look at it I would want them to post the project if possible... so thats what I did, but will also make a compilable example for you. :)   just wait like 5 to 10 min and check back if you wish

Comment: made a SSCCE and it works... I don't know why that one works and the other one does not. Did exactly the same things and even copied the methods over. I guess it is because something is not static... idk

Comment: Hm,... well nothing really should be static. You will need to do more debugging to try to isolate the error, I think. 1+ for the sscce though.

Comment: ya, I didn't know about that so thanks. did learn something from you. Also I got it to work so I will answer my own question. Was so stupid of me, I forgot to re create graphics when I resized my atlas. Thanks! :)

Comment: :) Great! Glad you've got it solved! And on your own too!